# How do I get R-shiny to select an element from a list

Tags: r, shiny

This seems like it should be really easy to do, so I'm probably making a simple error, but I have spent a lot of time on this without any success.

I am selecting a value from a drop-down box and want to get back the corresponding element from a list. I have now reduced this down to some very simple code, and it's still not working. I expect to get the output "test: one 1", "test: two 2" or "test: three 3", but only get "test: 1", "test: 2" or "test 3".

R 3.0.2, shiny_0.10.1

**Example:**
**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("test"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(      
      selectInput("number", label = h3("Select"), 
              choices = list("First" = 1, "Second" = 2, "Third" = 3), selected = 1)
),
mainPanel(
  textOutput("text1")
))))
```

**Server.R**

```
# server.R
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$text1 <- renderText({
    test<-list("one","two","three")[[input$number]]
    paste("test:",test,input$number)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recast your `input$number`:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$text1 <- renderText({
    test<-list("one","two","three")[[as.integer(input$number)]]
    paste("test:",test,input$number)
  })
})
```